# Derivative of matrix involving trace and log

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm stuck on this problem.
Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, compute the following matrix derivatives
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\mathrm{tr}(\log(XA)\log(XA)^\top),$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\mathrm{tr}(B\log(XA)), $$
where $\log(\cdot)$ is the matrix logarithm (not element-wise) and $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are constant matrices.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Do you know the chain rule and product rule?

Comment: Of course in the scalar case, but I still have a doubt: are these rules applicable without changes also in the matrix case? How about the order of derivation in the latter case? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are able to compute the derivative without trace. And the rest part, actually, is not hard. Try to compute it componentwisely, then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}\text{tr}f(X)=&
\frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}f^k_l(X)\delta^l_k\\
=&\frac d{dx}f^k_m(x)|_{x=X}\frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}X^m_l\delta^l_k\\
=&\frac d{dx}f^k_m(x)|_{x=X}\delta^m_i\delta^j_l\delta^l_k\\
=&\frac d{dx}f^j_i(x)|_{x=X}
\end{align}$$
The conclusion is

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\text{tr}f(X)=\left(\frac d{dx}f(x)|_{x=X}\right)^T$$

Comment: This is not quite clear to me. If e.g. $f(x) = x \log(x)$ and $f'(x) = \log(x) + 1$, what then is $f'(x)_{x = X}$? I suppose it is $\log(X) + 1$, where 1 is the matrix full of ones, but does this follow from what you have written?

Comment: The guess with the matrix full of ones comes from the fact that [http://www.matrixcalculus.org/](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) gives (for a symmetric matrix $X$) $\frac{d}{d X} \text{tr}(X \log(X)) = \log(X) + \text{matrix}(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the calculation is quasi-unfeasible. In particular, the answer of GMB is absolutely false (cf. my comment above). Who has given  a good point to his answer ?
Yet, one can give a compact answer if $X=A^{-1}$ because $D\log_I=id$.

Let $f(X)=tr(B\log(XA))$. Then $Df_{A^{-1}}:H\rightarrow tr(BHA)$. Thus $\nabla (f)_{A^{-1}}=(AB)^T$.

EDIT: Let $h(X)=tr(\log(I+X))$ where $\log$ denotes the principal logarithm and $||X||<1$. Then $h(X)=tr(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}/k.X^k)
 =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}/k.tr(X^k)$ and $Dh_X:H\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}/k.tr(kX^{k-1}H)$ (because $tr(UV)=tr(VU)$)$=tr(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}X^{k-1}H)=tr((I+X)^{-1}H)$. In other words $\nabla(h)_X={(I+X)^{-1}}^T$. More generally, if $X$ has no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}^-$, then let $g(X)=tr(\log(X))$. One has $Dg_X:H\rightarrow tr(X^{-1}H)$ and $\nabla(g)_X={X^{-1}}^T$.

Here $f(X)=tr(B\log(XA))=tr(B\log(Y))$; then we must derive $u(Y)=tr(BY^k)$. Unfortunately $Du_Y:K\rightarrow tr(B(kY^{k-1})K)$ is false in general ; yet, it is true if, for instance, $BY=YB$.
 Finally, when $BXA=XAB$, $Df_X:H\rightarrow tr(B(XA)^{-1}HA)$ (because $K=HA$)$=tr((XA)^{-1}BHA)=tr(X^{-1}BH)$ and $\nabla(f)_X=(X^{-1}B)^T$ does not depend on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\notimplies{\;{\large\not}\!\!\!\!\!\implies}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Denote the function $\Phi(\l)$ of a scalar $\l\,$ and its derivative
$$\phi(\l) = \frac{d\Phi}{d\l}$$
and write Shuchang's matrix result as a differential expression
$$\eqalign{
d\trace{{\large\Phi}(X)} &= \phi\!\LR{X^T} :dX \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the Frobenius product
$$\trace{A^TB} \;=\; A:B \;=\; A^T:B^T $$

Let's also define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
Y &= XA
 &\implies\quad Y^{-1} = A^{-1}X^{-1} \\
L &= \log(Y) &\;\notimplies\quad L = \log(X) + \log(A) \\
}$$
Consider a function to which Shuchang's result can be applied, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{L} \\
 &= \trace{\log(Y)} \\
d\phi
 &= \LR{Y^T}^{-1}:dY \\
 &= \LR{Y^{-1}}^T:\LR{dX\,A} \\
 &= \LR{Y^{-1}}^TA^T:dX \\
 &= \LR{AY^{-1}}^T:dX \\
 &= \LR{X^{-1}}^T:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= \LR{X^T}^{-1} \\
}$$
But differentiation of the functions posed in this question get stuck after the very first step !
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{B^TL} = B:L \\
d\phi &= B:dL \\
\\
\psi &= \trace{LL^T} = L:L \\
d\psi &= 2L:dL \\
}$$
The problem is that no simple expression for $dL\,($in terms of $dX)$ exists. Note that Shuchang's result applies to the **trace** of  $dL$ and not to $dL$ itself, so it cannot be used here.

The standard approach is to employ a power series, but one much more complicated than that proposed by GMB $\,($who naively assumed that $A$ commutes with $dA).\,$

While the power series approach yields a solution, it's complicated, has a tiny radius of convergence, and when it does converge it is so slow that it's practically useless.

Since high quality algorithms exist for evaluating matrix logarithms, a better approach is to calculate $dL$ via the logarithm of a block-triangular matrix
$$\eqalign{
&\m{L&dL\\0&L} =
 \log\L(\m{Y&dY\\0&Y}\R) =
 \log\L(\m{X&dX\\0&X}\cdot\m{A&0\\0&A}\R) \\
\\
d\phi = &\m{0&B\\0&0}:\log\L(\m{X&dX\\0&X}\cdot\m{A&0\\0&A}\R) \\
\\
d\psi = &\m{0&2L\\0&0}:\log\L(\m{X&dX\\0&X}\cdot\m{A&0\\0&A}\R) \\
}$$
These expressions are straightforward and accurate. All of the problematic non-commutative behavior is handled by the block structure of the function argument.

Despite the fact that $dX$ appears within a function argument,
these formulas represent a practical way to calculate
**directional derivatives.** Simply set $dX$ parallel to the direction of interest and scale it to have unit norm.

In summary, there are no closed-form solutions for
$\,\large\grad{\phi}{X}\,$ or $\,\large\grad{\psi}{X}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an incomplete answer:

$\log A = - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \, \frac{1}{i}(I - A)^i$

So

$d \log A = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \, (I - A)^i \, dA$

If you know the chain and product rules, deriving over the $\log A$ term should be the only tricky part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I was looking for a closed-form expression (if there exists).

Comment: Hi Levdub,the notation $df$ is really catastrophic. Here $A$ and $dA$ do not commute. The derivative of the function $log$ (and of the function $exp$) is complicate. For instance, the derivative of $f(A)=-(I-A)^3$ is $Df_A:H\rightarrow H(I-A)^2+(I-A)H(I-A)+(I-A)^2H$.