# Calculating the differential of the inverse of matrix exp?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups, matrix-calculus

Let $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ be two matrix-valued smooth function satisfying the equation, $B(t) = e^{A(t)}$. I need to express $\frac{dA(t)}{dt}$ in terms of $B(t)$. I know that there is a formula of Wilcox, namely
$$ \frac{d}{dt} e^{A(t)} = \int_0^1 e^{s A(t) } \frac{dA(t)}{dt}  e^{(1-s) A(t) } ds.$$
But I need something of the opposite direction. Does anyone know if there is such a formula or a general method to calculate that?

Comment: wouldn't work as $A=\ln B$, which then you differentiate?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. And what I'm asking is whether there is a formula to express $\frac{d}{dt} \operatorname{ln} B(t)$ in terms of $\operatorname{ln}$, $\frac{d}{dt} B(t)$ and $B(t)$ just like Wilcox's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log(U)$, the principal $\log$ is defined when $U$ has no $\leq 0$ eigenvalues. Note that $B=e^A$ implies that $A=\log(B)$ only when, for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $im(\lambda)\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Assume that $A(t)=\log(B(t))$; then (*) $A'(t)=\int_0^1(u(B-I_n)+I_n)^{-1}B'(t)(u(B-I_n)+I_n)^{-1}du$.

EDIT. That follows is a proof of the previous formula (*).

Step 1. (**)  $\log(A)=\int_0^1(A-I)(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}du$. Proof. Since the principal logarithm $\log()$ is $C^{\infty}$ over $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$, it suffices to prove the result when $A$ is diagonalizable (by density and continuity) and even only when $A$ is diagonal, that is easy.

Step 2. The derivative (with respect to $t$) of (**) is $(\log(A))'=\int_0^1A'(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}du-\int_0^1(A-I)(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}uA'(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}du=$

$\int_0^1 ZA'(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}du$ where $Z=I-u(A-I)(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}=(u(A-I)+I-u(A-I))(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}=(u(A-I)+I)^{-1}$

and we are done.

Comment: What do you mean by little $u$ ?

Comment: @loup-blanc: how did you come up with the formula?

Comment: @ Chip . See the book by Higham: Functions of matrices. Inside, a proof in the form of an exercise.

Comment: thanks for the reference, @loup-blanc!

Comment: @ chip . If you are interested by my post, then upvote it .

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $$ e^A = I + A + \frac{A^2}{2} +\cdots $$

If $A=A(0)+A'(0)t + \frac{A''(0)t^2}{2} + \cdots $, then \begin{align} e^A =& I
+ (A(0)+ A'(0)t) + \frac{ A(0)^2 + t(A(0)A'(0)+A'(0)A(0) ) }{2} +
\cdots \\& + \frac{ A(0)^n + t \sum_{i=1}^n A(0)\cdots\underbrace{
A'(0)}_{=i-th}\cdots A(0) }{n!} +\cdots + O(t^2) \end{align}

Then $$ B'(0)=\frac{d}{dt} e^A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^n
\frac{A(0)\cdots\underbrace{ A'(0)}_{=i-th}\cdots A(0) }{n!} $$